# Probability of drawing at least 3 cards from each suit when drawing 13 cards from a 52 card deck?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So to find the probability, I first tried to find how many combinations I could have total.

Combination 1: 4Suit 1, 3 each from the rest.
Combination 2: 4 from suit 2 and 3 each from the rest.
This repeats 2 more times.
(4,3,3,3),(3,4,3,3,),(3,3,4,3),(3,3,3,4) are the 4 combinations I found.

Is it correct go just add each combination?
So each one would be structured like:

(4 choose 1)^4(13 choose 4)*3[(4 choose 1)^3(13 choose 3)]

or so that's how I would go about it. This would give combination for one suit having 4 so the answer would I assume be 4* the combination above.

Then to find the probability, I would just divide by (52 choose 13)

Answer (score 3):

You’ve not counted the hands of the desired type correctly.

There are $4$ ways to choose the suit that gets $4$ cards. Once you’ve decided that, there are $\binom{13}4$ ways to choose the $4$ cards from that suit, and for each of the other $3$ suits there are $\binom{13}3$ ways to choose $3$ cards. Thus, there are

$$4\binom{13}4\binom{13}3^3$$

ways to choose a hand of the desired type. As you say, there are $\binom{52}{13}$ possible hands, so the desired probability is

$$\frac{4\binom{13}4\binom{13}3^3}{\binom{52}{13}}\;.$$